# Consider function f(x)=$\sqrt{x}$ and $p_n(x)$ as its Taylor polynomial of degree n about the point x=9 can you prove as n increases error decreases?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $p_n(x)$ as its Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ about the point $x=9$.we want to compute the $E_n$ of $p_n(16)$(error). Can you prove as $n$ increases error decreases?
I wanted to prove that $\frac{E_n}{E_{n-1}}<1$ and I did (its just a bunch of calculations) but someone said it was wrong and didn't say why.
Is there a way to prove error always decreases as $n$ increases?

Comment: I think it'd be nice if you included your work for showing that $E_n$ is decreasing, so we can determine whether or not you were actually correct.

Comment: You can try to use the formula for the remainder in Taylor's approximation.

Comment: If the polynomial is centred at $a$ and $h$ is the "increment" (in your case $a = 9$ and $h = 7$), then $E_n = |f(x) - p_n(x)| \leq \dfrac{M_n}{(n+1)!} |h|^n,$ where $M_n$ is the maximum on the $(n+1)$th derivative of $f$ between $a$ and $a+h.$ The bound can be attained (at least for some values of $n$, unlikely for all values of $n$). At any rate, the right hand side need not tendo to zero as $M_n$ could grow quite wildly (the function becomes more and more vertical, more and more rapidly). For $t \to \sqrt{t}$, however, $M_n$ tends to zero (the functions becomes more and more flatter).

Comment: The Taylor expansion has centered at 9 has a radius of convergence of 9.  Inside the radius of convergence you can show that the error gets smaller, but outside this radius, you can't because it doesn't

Comment: @DougM the radius of convergence is 9 because of the left hand side, the convergence could perfectly occur all the way to infinity on the right (I believe the convergence on the right hand side is longer than 9).

Comment: @WillM.  If you investigate the power series, you will see that it does not converge to the right beyond 9.